# DOJO Tooltip gives "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function "

Tags: javascript, dojo, tooltip, amd

I have the following code that tries to use a `dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip`:

```
require([
    "dojox/charting/Chart",
    "dojox/charting/themes/Claro",
    "dojox/charting/plot2d/MarkersOnly",
    "dojox/charting/plot2d/Columns",
    "dojox/fx/easing",
    "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
    "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
    "dojo/ready"
], function(Chart, Theme, MarkersOnly, easing, Tooltip, Columns, Default, ready) {

        ready(function(){
                var chart1 = new Chart("chartArea");
                chart1.setTheme(Theme);
                chart1.addPlot("budget", {type: "MarkersOnly"});
                chart1.addPlot("actual", {type: "Columns", gap: 3, animate: { duration: 300, easing: dojox.fx.easing.linear}});

                //add the axis (both x and y) below
                chart1.addAxis("x",{labels: [
                    {value:1, text: "01 - AXA"},{value:2, text: "02 - MR"},{value:3, text: "03 - CT"},{value:4, text: "04 - XP WH"},                                              
                    {value:5, text: "06 - XP RF"},{value:6, text: "07 - XPC"},{value:7, text: "09 - ECS"},{value:8, text: "10 - XPU"}], 
                     rotation:-90, 
                     font: "normal normal bold 12pt Arial"
                });//end adding axis to the chart
                chart1.addAxis("y", {vertical: true, font: "normal normal bold 12pt Arial"});

                chart1.addSeries("Series 2", [80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80], {plot:"budget"});
                //chart1.addSeries("Series 1", [73,71,78,93,70,,,83,100,,,], {plot:"actual"});
                chart1.addSeries("Series 1", [{y:75, tooltip:"custom"},{y:71},{y:78},{y:93},{y:70},{y:83},{y:100}], {plot:"actual"});


                var tip = new Tooltip(chart1, "default");  
                chart1.render();
        });//end of DOJO ready
    });//end function chart stuff
```

and DOJO gives me the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

I can figure out why the issue is coming up, especially since i've found multiple examples handling it this way. anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dependency list and your list of arguments to the callback don't match up.

```
require([
    "dojox/charting/Chart",
    "dojox/charting/themes/Claro",
    "dojox/charting/plot2d/MarkersOnly", 
    "dojox/charting/plot2d/Columns",
    "dojox/fx/easing",
    "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
    "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
    "dojo/ready"
], function(Chart, Theme, MarkersOnly, Columns, easing, Tooltip, Default, ready) { /* ... */ });
```

Note the different order of the arguments: `Columns` comes after `MarkersOnly`.

With the order you had your arguments, `Tooltip` was pointing to the `dojo/fx/easing` module and giving you the error you described.

Comment: That is a great catch! thank you. while that does help. For some strange reason now that line (the tooltip line of the code) spits out "cannot read property 'name' of undefined. chart1 is defined and used a bunch of times before hitting the tooltip, is there something wrong I am doing with the rest of my code causing the tooltip line to error out?

Comment: `var tip = new Tooltip(chart1, "default");` – You don't have a plot named "default". You need to specify a plot that exists ("budget" or "actual") to attach to.

Comment: Perfect that worked! I also needed to import the claro stylesheet into the web page in order to make work and not appear in the bottom of the page and actually appear on the chart (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dojo/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css">) thanks.